# Вывод изображения записи (поста) wordpress в ReactJS

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

В моем компоненте выводятся посты из вордпресса по rest api. Но вот не получается вывести изображение записи (thumbnails). Как это лучше сделать?

```
import Img from './Img';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
const BLOG_API = `http://localhost/test-digital/`;

class Posts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = { // инициализируем состояние по-умолчанию
          posts: []
        };
 
      }

      componentWillMount () {
        return fetch(BLOG_API + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=4' ) // делаем запрос к Wordpress API и получаем только первые четыре записи
        .then((response) => response.json()) // получаем ответ в формате json
        .then(posts => {
          this.setState({
            posts: posts, // обновляем состояние страницы
          })
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ul> 
              {
                this.state.posts.map(item => (
                  <li key={item.id}>
                    <Link to={`/test-digital/${item.id}`}>
                        <Img/>
                        <p>{item.title.rendered}</p>
                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html : item.excerpt.rendered }}></div>
                        <p>{item.date}</p>
                    </Link>                    
                  </li>
                ))
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

export default Posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Получаете `ID` - изображения в `post.featured_media`

И получаете данные картинки из API: `/wp-json/wp/v2/media/{ID}`. Дальше разберетесь.

Comment: Это получается мне нужен еще плюс целый компонент что бы просто отрендерить картинку и передать ее родителю?(

Comment: Наверное нужен)

Comment: Примерно логику понял, но вот у меня не выходит отрендерить конкретную картинку к конкретной записи. Сейчас выводятся все картинки к каждому посту.. (код выше добавил)